# Fix Downloaded Image Width & Height

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a list of image URLs in my sheet. The problem is when I download the image in a cell its so small and I want to make it bigger also code stop's working if a bad URL is present.

```
}

function getImages(){

  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 
  for (let i = 0; i < lastRow-1; i++){
  let url = sheet.getRange(2+i,10).getValues();
  let image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url);
   
    sheet.getRange(2+i,10).setValue(image);
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `The problem is when I download the image in a cell its so small and I want to make it bigger`, in this case, the image is put into a cell. So, how about increasing the cell width and height?
- About `code stop's working if a bad URL is present.`, When the URL is invalid URL, it seems that an error occurs at `sheet.getRange(2 + i, 10).setValue(image);`.
- In your script, `getValues` and `setValues` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getImages() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // I modified below script.
  // 1. Retrieve URLs from cells "J2:J".
  const range = sheet.getRange("J2:J" + lastRow);
  const values = range.getValues();
  
  // 2. Check URLs.
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(values.map(([j]) => ({ url: j, muteHttpExceptions: true })));
  
  // 3. Create an array including CellImage object.
  const v = res.map((r, i) => [r.getResponseCode() == 200 ? SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(values[i][0]).build() : null]);
  
  // 4. Put the array.
  range.setValues(v);
  
  // 5. Increase row height and column width.
  sheet.setRowHeights(2, lastRow - 1, 100).setColumnWidth(10, 500);
}
```

- In this modification, the following flow is run.

  1. Retrieve URLs from cells "J2:J".
  2. Check URLs.
  3. Create an array including CellImage object.
  4. Put the array.
  5. Increase row height and column width.
- When you want to adjust the row height and column width, please modify `sheet.setRowHeights(2, lastRow - 1, 100).setColumnWidth(10, 500);`.
- In this sample, the invalid URL is converted to `null`. If you want to leave the URL, please modify `null` to `values[i][0]`.

#### Note:

- When your script is modified, the following modification can be also used. In this case, try-catch is used.

  ```
    function getImages() {
      let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      for (let i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++) {
        let url = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 10).getValue();
        let image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url).build();
        try {
          sheet.getRange(2 + i, 10).setValue(image);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message)
        }
      }
      sheet.setRowHeights(2, lastRow - 1, 100).setColumnWidth(10, 500);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [setRowHeights(startRow, numRows, height)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightsstartrow,-numrows,-height)
- [setColumnWidth(columnPosition, width)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setcolumnwidthcolumnposition,-width)

Comment: it works like a charm but i notice one problem if i have more then 1000 images to download then apps script time limit expire. can you please add the time Triger in it to fix this problem.

Comment: @tamey Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue of `but i notice one problem if i have more then 1000 images to download then apps script time limit expire. can you please add the time Triger in it to fix this problem.`, in this case, I would like to propose posting it as a new question. Because your new issue is different from your this question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: i will definitely and I have a lot of other questions in mind i will post them one by one hopefully you will help me to fix them.